# How to send entire text into a text area using selenium in python instead of sending it line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My code inputs text into the text area of the web page , line by line, how to make it insert the entire text all at once instead, is there a solution for this?
because line by line takes a lot of time

```
def Translated_Content(content):

    driver= webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\shricharan.arumugam\\Desktop\\PDF2txt\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get('https://translate.shell.com/')

    input_box = driver.find_element_by_id('translateText')
    input_box.send_keys(content)

    translate_button = driver.find_element_by_id('translate')
    translate_button.click()
    translated_text_element= driver.find_element_by_id('translatedText')
    time.sleep(4)


    translated_text=translated_text_element.get_attribute('value')

    driver.close()

    return translated_text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the entire chunk of text into the `<textarea>` using selenium through *Python* to speed up the process you can inject a script and use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  myText = """No, there is no way to hide the console window of the chromedriver.exe 
      in the .NET bindings without modifying the bindings source code. This is seen 
      as a feature of the bindings, as it makes it very easy to see when your code 
      hasn't correctly cleaned up the resources of the ChromeDriver, since the console window 
      remains open. In the case of some other languages, if your code does not properly clean up 
      the instance of ChromeDriver by calling the quit() method on the WebDriver object, 
      you can end up with a zombie chromedriver.exe process running on your machine.""" 
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://translate.shell.com/')
  translate_from = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.form-control#translateText")))
  translate_from._parent.execute_script("""
      var elm = arguments[0], text = arguments[1];
      if (!('value' in elm))
        throw new Error('Expected an <input> or <textarea>');
      elm.focus();
      elm.value = text;
      elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
      """, translate_from, myText)
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#translate").click()
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: ChunkOfText]

Answer (score 6):

You can change the text of textbox/textarea through JavaScript DOM API in silent way, not from front UI:

```
long_string= <the long string>
input_box = driver.find_element_by_id('translateText')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', input_box, long_string)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Much cleaner than code chosen as best answer.

Comment: Can I run a function where there is a for loop in it which prints text and numbers . How to run a python function in selenium?

Comment: I think it's no way to do that.  Actually, the  '<script>'  in `execute_script(<script>)` is executed in browser,  browser can't run python script.