# Python Selenium chrome - how to disable user input

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is a simple code which opens a google chrome instance and then enters the text "This is some very long text".

Is there a way to disable user keyboard input while the above text is being typed in google chrome? 
The goal would be that the user can not enter anything by mistake on that page while working parallely on the computer on other things.

I understand that one option would be to take the chrome instance "headless" but that is not an option for the website I want to work on.

What I have done so far:

I had a look at the selenium docs at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
but I could not find any such option.

But then again, the above website does not have info on "--disable-notifications" which is something you can use with selenium chrome. So, maybe there is a chance that there is some hidden way to do what I am looking for.

Also checked https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ but no luck

```
import time, datetime, sys, os
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


CHROME_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '..\\chromedriver.exe' #location of your chromedriver.exe
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

chrome_options = Options()  
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")

elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#lst-ib')
if not elements:
    print("NO SUCH ELEMENT FOUND!")
    print("Fatal Error:Please perform all tasks manually")
else:
    item1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#lst-ib')
    item1.send_keys('This is some very long text'+Keys.TAB)
```

Or if anyone can point me in which direction I should be doing my research, that would be great too!!
Thanks

Comment: Selenium utilizes user input methods to allow typing.  I don't think there would be reasonable way to disable user input and allow your script to simulate a user typing.  If you cannot run the script in headless mode, then I would suggest setting up a virtual machine to run the script.

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679605/how-to-send-entire-text-into-a-text-area-using-selenium-in-python-instead-of-sen

Comment: why isn't headless an option?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, cause in headless mode, for my specific page(not google) , I am blocked out saying "401 unauthorized access is denied due to invalid credentials"

Comment: @Stan, that just means basic authentication is blocking you.  headless shouldn't affect that.  If it does, file a bug with selenium or chromedriver.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you wanted`

```
import time, datetime, sys, os
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CHROME_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:\\python27\\chromedriver.exe'  # location of your 
chromedriver.exe
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, 
chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")

elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#lst-ib')
if not elements:
    print("NO SUCH ELEMENT FOUND!")
    print("Fatal Error:Please perform all tasks manually")
else:
    browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("lst-ib").onkeypress=function()          
        {return false;}')
    browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "this is some           
        text"')
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted??

Comment: to a certain extent yes...though ideal would have been a situation where the user is not able to interact with the chrome window at all

Comment: I don't think so its possible to completely take away the control of the browser from the client

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the kiosk mode option once...

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")
```

Comment: thanks, but that still doesnt solve the problem that when I enter something, the text "This is some very long text" gets corrupted

Comment: you need to disable the user from inputting in "lst-ib"(id) text input area?and if so u need to prevent them after "this is some text" has been inputted or before that

Comment: effectively I dont want the user to be able to do any interaction whatsoever with this automated chrome window. Neither before nor after.