# executed_script failed to send long text despite send_keys works well

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, sendkeys

I'm trying to send a long text (above 1000 words) to the body of the `iframe`.
I use `send_keys` and it works smoothly but it's too slow so I was looking for some solutions to improve that speed.
I realized that the use of `execute_script`, like below, can solve the problem of speed:

```
browserdriver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML = "%s"' % body_text)
```

I tested that code with a short sentence and it works well, but when I try my real input (a product description including many different sentences and paragraphs), it shows the error that:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

However, if using:

```
webelement.send_keys(body_text)
```

it works well, but slow.

Is there any solution to solve this problem of my code of `execute_script`?

EDIT:
I have read this post:
[How to send entire text into a text area using selenium in python instead of sending it line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679605/how-to-send-entire-text-into-a-text-area-using-selenium-in-python-instead-of-sen)
And I practiced it by posting on google translate site and it works well.
But when I applied it to my case. It turned out the error that:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Expected an <input> or <textarea>
```

And here is the html in my case:

```
<iframe id="mce_0_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Bấm ALT-F9 mở menu. Bấm ALT-F10 mở thanh công cụ. Bấm ALT-0 mở trợ giúp" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; display: block;" cd_frame_id_="4a3608c987a6e635206f3831764c495e"></iframe>
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="mce_0" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><p></p></body>
```